# How to abbreviate large numbers in a i18n-friendly way?

Tags: internationalization

I want to "abbreviate" large numbers to make them human-readable, using abbreviations that are idiomatic for a given locale. For example, the number `16512` would become:

- `"16.5k"` for `en-US` ("k" is short for the Metric prefix "thousand", as in "kilometer")
- `"16,5тыс."` for `ru` ("тыс." is short for "тысяча", meaning "thousand" in Russian)

I'm not sure what to call this procedure I'm describing.

Ruby on Rails has something similar to what I'm looking for called [`#number_to_human`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human), but it's not quite right -- it would return `"16.5 Thousand"` in my example above. I'm interested in *abbreviations* (and perhaps not all locales round things to the nearest thousand), not merely making strings human-readable.

I'd be especially interested in a solution that works for JavaScript, but even the name of this procedure would be a huge help!

Comment: Look at [globalize.js](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize). It use Unicode CLDR data and written in javascript.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan I don't believe globalize.js helps here; I see number- and currency-formatting methods, but none of them do the task I describe. In fact, I don't think globalize.js does anything I couldn't do with the `Intl.NumberFormat` API. Nor do I see any useful data in the CLDR, unless I've missed something?

Comment: Never mind, I think you're right, @NiyokoYuliawan! The name of what I'm looking for is a "short" number. [CLDR does have short number data](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/number-patterns#TOC-Short-Numbers). Unfortunately, globalize.js has not yet implemented it. There is an issue for it, though: [#406](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/issues/406).

Answer (score 10):

Answering my own question:

The procedure I'm describing is known as *compact number formatting*. There are two variants: *short* (`"16.5K"`) and *long* (`"16.5 Thousand"`). The Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR) provides number-formatting patterns for compact numbers in each locale: http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/number-patterns#TOC-Short-Numbers

For JavaScript, there is a (stalled) ECMA proposal to add a `compact` option to the `Intl.NumberFormat` API: https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/37

Luckily for Ruby and JS programmers, Twitter has an NPM package called `twitter_cldr` (documentation is [here](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-cldr-js) and [here](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-cldr-npm)). Usage looks like this:

```
const TwitterCldr = require('twitter_cldr');

function printNumbers(localeName) {
    const locale = TwitterCldr.load(localeName);
    const formatter = new locale.ShortDecimalFormatter();

    const numbers = [123, 1231, 12312, 123123, 1231231, 12312312, 123123123];
    return numbers.map(n => formatter.format(n, { precision: 1 }));
}

console.log(printNumbers('en'));
// [ '123.0', '1.2K', '12.3K', '123.1K', '1.2M', '12.3M', '123.1M' ]
console.log(printNumbers('ru'));
// [ '123,0', '1,2 тыс.', '12,3 тыс.', '123,1 тыс.', '1,2 млн', '12,3 млн', 123,1 млн' ]
console.log(printNumbers('ja'));
// [ '123.0', '1.2千', '1.2万', '12.3万', '123.1万', '1231.2万', '1.2億' ]
```

Note that in Japan, people wouldn't say "12.3 Million", they'd say "1231.2 Ten-Thousand". Add that to the list of falsehoods programmers assume about the world!